# Isn't git-flow a bit ambiguous when it comes to raising MR for code reviews?

Tags: git, gitlab, release-management, git-flow, github-codereviews

I am new to using `git-flow` and have got some queries.
Let's say I have `master` & `dev` branches created upon `git flow init` and
`feature/master-api` branch made from `dev` branch.

Once I complete the feature I do `git flow feature finish master-api`. The feature branch gets merged into my local `dev` branch.

Are my team members supposed to create a new branch from `dev` and raise an MR to `dev`?

Same goes when doing `git flow release finish 1.0.0.1`. Code gets merged into local `master` branch and back-merged into local `dev`.

`dev` and `master` (maybe `release/`) branches are supposed to be `protected` branches.

So how do we manage MR for code reviews?

Comment: Git by itself does not have a notion of branch protection. So this is usually not enforced (locally). It is possible to have remote servers restrict commits pushed to a certain branch to only contain merge commits though. – But I think if you want to establish branch protection and code review properly, then you just don’t use `git flow feature finish`. You just create a PR into the target branch yourself.

Comment: That's the reason I feel `git flow` to be incomplete. Almost all organisations will have these branches protected to support code-reviews. `git flow` without `git flow feature finish` will just provide some branch naming conventions.

Comment: Yes, Git Flow is just a set of conventions with a guideline for a workflow. It does not replace other things as part of your workflow if you want to enforce different things, and it’s generally also not a strict guideline that easily applies to _every_ project. You should evaluate what your project needs and then adjust the workflow to match your project.